# How to pass Github secrets as value in json file?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, cypress, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm using [Cypress.io](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress) for my automated tests & triggering it in CI/D with [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions). The config `cypress.json` file has nested `env` values like so:

```json
{
  "baseUrl": "<url-to-login>",
  "env": {
    "roles": {
      "admin": {
        "PASSWORD": "<password>",
        "USERNAME": "<username>"
      },
      "employee": {
        "PASSWORD": "<password>",
        "USERNAME": "<username>"
      },
      "client": {
        "PASSWORD": "<password>",
        "USERNAME": "<username>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, [Cypress can't access deeply env variables](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1736) so I'm creating the config `cypress.json` like so:

```yaml
name: Cypress Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        # creates cypress.json file to run Cypress
      - name: Create Cypress config files
        run: |
          echo '{ "baseUrl": "${{ secrets.BASE_URL }}", "env": { "roles": { "admin": { "PASSWORD": "${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}", "USERNAME": "${{ secrets.USERNAME }}" } } } }' > cypress.json
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: yarn run
          start: yarn cypress:run
          wait-on-timeout: 120
          browser: chrome
```

It doesn't work, but I hardcoded the values it did work like so:

```yaml
run: |
          echo '{ "baseUrl": "<hardcoded-redacted-value>", "env": { "roles": { "admin": { "PASSWORD": "<hardcoded-redacted-value>", "USERNAME": "<hardcoded-redacted-value>" } } } }' > cypress.json
```

So my question is, how to pass the secret in the `json` file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this issue by storing the entire `cypress.json` config file's content as [GitHub's repository encrypted secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-an-environment). Then, I used the [`create-json` GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-json) to generate the `cypress.json` needed to run [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) on CI/CD. This is the final `.github/workflows/main.yml` file:

```yaml
name: Cypress Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: create-json
        id: create-json
        uses: jsdaniell/create-json@1.1.2
        with:
          name: "cypress.json"
          json: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_CONFIG_JSON }}
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: yarn run
          start: yarn cypress:run
          wait-on-timeout: 120
          browser: chrome
```

Comment: So, nothing to do with deeply nested env variables then?

Comment: How do i add path where to  store json file?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. We just need to change file name like path/to/file.json

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue using,

1. Base64 encoding the value of the json file.

```
echo cypress.json | base64
```

2. Store the encrypted value as a Github Action Secret as `CYPRESS_CONFIG_JSON`
3. Populate the `cypress.json` using base64 decode

```
name: Cypress Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        # creates cypress.json file to run Cypress
      - name: Create Cypress config files
        run: |
          echo ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_CONFIG_JSON }} | base64 -d > cypress.json
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: yarn run
          start: yarn cypress:run
          wait-on-timeout: 120
          browser: chrome
```

Comment: I just want to point out that the output of base64 is not encrypted. It is _encoded_, which is very different than encrypted.

Comment: Probably the solution should be updated with `cat filename.json | base64`, else `echo filename.json | base64` with encode the file name, not the file content

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find it was fixed [check for undefined values on setPluginResolvedOn function #7960](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/7960#pullrequestreview-449516490)

```js
const roles = Cypress.env('roles') 
expect(roles.client.PASSWORD).to.eq('<password>')   // ✅ passes
```